# Mathematical Logic: Predicate Calculus Proof Verificacion

Tags: logic

Is this proof correct? Thank you so much for your help!

***Premise:***

1) $\exists y (My \land \forall x (Mx \rightarrow Dxy))$

***Conclusion:***

2) $\exists y (My \land Dyy)$

***Proof:***

3) $(Ma \land \forall x (Mx \rightarrow Dxa))$ ***Existential Instantiation 1) a/y flag a***

4) *Ma* ***Simplification 3)***

5) $\forall x (Mx \rightarrow Dxa)$ ***Simplification 3)***

6) $(Ma \rightarrow Daa)$ **Universal Instantiation 5) a/x**

7) *Daa* ***Modus Ponens 4) 6)***

8) $Ma \land Daa$ ***Conjunction 4) 7)***

9) $\exists y (My \land Dyy)$ ***Existential Generalization 8) a/y***

***Q.E.D.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the parentheses in 3, and on line 8 I think you should say $y/a$ but otherwise perfect!

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!